# VBA Script to Remove Duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I'm curious if there's any way I can substantially improve its speed (it runs through >200k rows). I think I'll most likely need this once, so please bear with me since it *probably* looks terrible.

Thanks for reading!

Code I would like reviewed:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim rBefore As Range
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Dim c_ As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim v_ As Variant
    Dim dupCount As Long
    Dim xlApp As Application
    Dim i As Long
    Dim size As Long

    Set xlApp = Excel.Application
    With xlApp
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .StatusBar = "Running Script..."
    End With


    Set wsSource = xlApp.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("source")
    Set rBefore = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(2, 1), wsSource.Cells(wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1))

    Set ws = xlApp.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("testSheet")
    Set r = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1))
    size = r.Count
    i = 1
    For Each v In r
        Set c = v

        DoEvents
        dupCount = 0
        For Each v_ In r
            Set c_ = v_

            DoEvents
            If CStr(c.Value) = CStr(c_.Value) Then
                dupCount = dupCount + 1
                If dupCount > 1 Then
                    c_.Rows(c_.Row).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next
        xlApp.StatusBar = Format(i & " out of " & size) & " Rows Complete"
        i = i + 1
    Next

    With xlApp
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ThisWorkbook.Save
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ThisWorkbook.Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Any reason why [Range.RemoveDuplicates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.RemoveDuplicates) can't be used here?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon None other than I didn't know about it until your comment; I'll check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems [`Range.RemoveDuplicates`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.RemoveDuplicates) could turn it all into a much more efficient one-liner.

Stylistically though, the code could use some help anyway.

The rather procedure begins with a good dozen variable declarations. Code is easier to follow when you don't need to constantly scroll up and down and back to know what's what: by declaring variables closer to their usage, you reduce the cognitive load and avoid that scrolling.

```
Dim xlApp As Application
Set xlApp = Excel.Application
```

Now, there's no need for this variable; `Application` is free, globally-scoped, and you're not owning that instance - just copying a reference to an existing object. Don't do that, use the globals that are right there waiting to be referenced instead. This includes any worksheet that exist at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Set wsSource = xlApp.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("source")
```

Every worksheet has a `CodeName` property, that you can change in the *properties* toolwindow (F4). Locate that "source" worksheet in the *Project Explorer*, then look at its `(Name)` property - change it from what defaults to e.g. `Sheet1`, to a meaningful identifier, e.g. `SourceSheet`. And now you have a free, global-scope worksheet object referring to *that specific sheet*, readily usable everywhere in that VBA project - which makes this `wsSource` variable redundant as well.

```
Dim rBefore As Range
Set rBefore = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(2, 1), wsSource.Cells(wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1))
```

It's not clear whether that `r` stands for `Range` (in which case it's useless Hungarian Notation), and `Before` what this range is. So we try to look at other usages to infer its meaning... and we don't find any: the variable is assigned, but the assigned reference isn't used anywhere - the variable is redundant and can be removed entirely.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = xlApp.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("testSheet")
```

Again, the `CodeName` could be `TestSheet`, and `ws` wouldn't be needed, provided that the worksheet exists at compile-time. Otherwise, kudos for fetching it from the `Worksheets` collection.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1))
```

`UsedRange` isn't a [reliable way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/1188513) to get the last row of a column.

`r` isn't a meaningful name. `testRange` would tell us it's from the `TestSheet`, but wouldn't convey what it *means* - any single-letter variable name can *never* tell us *anything* whatsoever about something's purpose. Unless it's `i` for a `For...Next` loop counter, which any programmer knows about; here `i` isn't used like that, it's more like some `processedRows`.

`DoEvents` inside the loop, combined with updating the status bar at every single iteration, is contributing to slowing things down.

You're disabling `ScreenUpdating`, automatic `Calculation`, etc.; but you leave `EnableEvents` enabled, so a worksheet event is fired whenever you delete a row. You could use `Union` to combine all the rows you want to delete, and then delete them all in one single operation - instead of deleting them one at a time. But then again, `Range.RemoveDuplicates` makes that moot.

There *are* a number of issues (it's a constant work-in-progress), but [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) could have picked up a number of the observations I made above. Kudos for `Option Explicit`, the meaningful name, and the explicit `Public` modifier on your macro!

Comment: Stylistically, I know it's garbage, but there's a wealth of info NuGets that didn't even cross my mind. Thanks for the detailed answer!